# I get these warning that you are behind on API level I'm use targetSDK 33 of my app but shows as API level 23+ while the requirement is API level 33

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play, google-play-services

I get these warning that you are behind on API level I'm use  targetSDK 33 of my app but shows as API level 23+ while the requirement is API level 33.

But I'm using the latest targetSdkVersion which is 33,but from google side sent mail like to update the latest targetSdkVersion.

what is the issue?

```
  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.abc.myApp"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 33
    versionCode 50
    versionName "5.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    ndk {
        debugSymbolLevel 'FULL'
    }
    ndkVersion "25.2.9519653"
}
```

Comment: There's a 23 in that config too. What do you think the issue is?

Comment: I started getting this warning when SDK 34 came out. I think they just jumped the gun on showing that warning, since 34 is still in beta.

Comment: I got mail from Google side like " We've detected that  your app are targeting an old version of Android. To provide users with a safe and secure experience, Google Play requires all apps to meet target API level requirements before Aug 31, 2023."
That's why I'm asking @Jorn

Comment: I think that email is sent out for all apps targeting less than 33, even though they only need to target 31 by August 31 to stay on the store.